# How to gather output from each core in MPI-Python and save as .npy file?

Tags: python, mpi

I have a main MPI python script(which I found online) which allot jobs to core if the number of task to be performed is greater than the no:of cores.

```
from mpi4py import MPI

import SubProgram
import numpy as np  

Output={};
def enum(*sequential, **named):

    enums = dict(zip(sequential, range(len(sequential))), **named)
    return type('Enum', (), enums)

# Define MPI message tags
tags = enum('READY', 'DONE', 'EXIT', 'START')

# Initializations and preliminaries
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD   # get MPI communicator object
size = comm.size        # total number of processes
rank = comm.rank        # rank of this process
status = MPI.Status()   # get MPI status object


if rank == 0:
    # Master process executes code below
    tasks = range(2)
    task_index = 0
    num_workers = size - 1
    closed_workers = 0
    print("Master starting with %d workers" % num_workers)
    while closed_workers < num_workers:
        data = comm.recv(source=MPI.ANY_SOURCE, tag=MPI.ANY_TAG, status=status)

        source = status.Get_source()
        tag = status.Get_tag()
        #print(source,tag)
        if tag == tags.READY:
            # Worker is ready, so send it a task
            if task_index < len(tasks):
                comm.send(tasks[task_index], dest=source, tag=tags.START)
                print("Sending task %d to worker %d" % (task_index, source))
                task_index += 1
            else: 
                comm.send(None, dest=source, tag=tags.EXIT)
        elif tag == tags.DONE:
           results = data
           print("Got data from worker %d" % source)
        elif tag == tags.EXIT:
           print("Worker %d exited." % source)
           closed_workers += 1

    print("Master finishing")
else:
    # Worker processes execute code below
    name = MPI.Get_processor_name()
    print("I am a worker with rank %d on %s." % (rank, name))
    while True:

        comm.send(None, dest=0, tag=tags.READY)
        task = comm.recv(source=0, tag=MPI.ANY_SOURCE, status=status)
        tag = status.Get_tag()



        if tag == tags.START:
            #calling the subprogram and the subprogram returns a list 
            Output[rank]=SubProgram.main(rank,name);

            NewOutput=comm.gather(Gene,root=0)

            result = task**2
            comm.send(result, dest=0, tag=tags.DONE)
        elif tag == tags.EXIT:
            break

    comm.send(None, dest=0, tag=tags.EXIT)
if rank==0:
    np.save('Output.npy',NewOutput)
```

SubProgram is a function which returns a list of arrays and each core return unique arrays. Something like this:-

```
[array([    1,   9613, 13037,  6789], dtype=int64),
array([  95,  5648, ..., 2387,  6790], dtype=int64),
array([  509,  1948,  2541,  2075], dtype=int64),
array([  594,   12091], dtype=int64),
array([  786,  4370,  8830,  5002,  5948, 11969], dtype=int64),
array([ 841, 4324, 9761, 7397, 6367], dtype=int64)]
```

So if I do run on 10 cores 1 will get 10 list. But when I use the above program 
the result is not being stored into .npy. I am new to Parallel programming. Can anyone please help me how to proceed.

Is there a way to gather these output and store it as a Dictionary  For eg:

```
{0:[array([    1,   9613, 13037,  6789], dtype=int64),
array([  95,  5648, ..., 2387,  6790], dtype=int64),
array([  509,  1948,  2541,  2075], dtype=int64),
array([  594,   12091], dtype=int64),
array([  786,  4370,  8830,  5002,  5948, 11969], dtype=int64),
array([ 841, 4324, 9761, 7397, 6367], dtype=int64)],


1: [array([    1,   843,  4665, ...,  9613, 13037,  6789], dtype=int64),
array([  95, 1939, 5648, ..., 2387, 5920, 6790], dtype=int64),
array([  509,  1948,  2541,  5417,  2421, 11452, 12863,  2075], dtype=int64),
array([  594,  3364, 12081,  7746,  2286,  9719, 12091], dtype=int64),
array([  786,  4370,  8830,  5002,  5948, 11969], dtype=int64),
array([ 841, 4324, 9761, 7389, 7697, 6367], dtype=int64)],


2: [array([    1,   843,  4665, ...,  9613, 13037,  6789], dtype=int64),
array([  95, 1939, 5648, ..., 2387, 5920, 6790], dtype=int64),
array([  509,  1948,  2541,  5417,  2421, 11452, 12863,  2075], dtype=int64),
array([  594,  3364, 12081,  7746,  2286,  9719, 12091], dtype=int64),
array([  786,  4370,  8830,  5002,  5948, 11969], dtype=int64),
array([ 841, 4324, 9761, 7389, 7697, 6367], dtype=int64)]
.................................

10:[array([10,63,89........],dtype=int64)]}          ]
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your code and removed

```
 Output[rank]=SubProgram.main(rank,name);
 NewOutput=comm.gather(Gene,root=0)
```

to create working example which gives me in variable `results` something like this

```
{
 1: [array([0]), array([16]), array([49])], 
 2: [array([9]), array([36]), array([81])], 
 3: [array([1])], 
 4: [array([4]), array([25]), array([64])]
}
```

It uses

```
        elif tag == tags.DONE:

            print("Got data from worker %d" % source)

            if source not in results:
                results[source] = []
            results[source].append(data)
```

Full code

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np

def enum(*sequential, **named):
    enums = dict(zip(sequential, range(len(sequential))), **named)
    return type('Enum', (), enums)

# Define MPI message tags
tags = enum('READY', 'DONE', 'EXIT', 'START')

# Initializations and preliminaries
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD   # get MPI communicator object
size = comm.size        # total number of processes
rank = comm.rank        # rank of this process
status = MPI.Status()   # get MPI status object

if rank == 0:
    # Master process executes code below
    tasks = range(10)
    task_index = 0

    num_workers = size - 1
    closed_workers = 0

    results = dict()

    print("Master starting with %d workers" % num_workers)

    while closed_workers < num_workers:

        data = comm.recv(source=MPI.ANY_SOURCE, tag=MPI.ANY_TAG, status=status)
        source = status.Get_source()
        tag = status.Get_tag()

        #print(source, tag)

        if tag == tags.READY:

            # Worker is ready, so send it a task
            if task_index < len(tasks):
                comm.send(tasks[task_index], dest=source, tag=tags.START)
                print("Sending task %d to worker %d" % (task_index, source))
                task_index += 1
            else: 
                comm.send(None, dest=source, tag=tags.EXIT)

        elif tag == tags.DONE:

            print("Got data from worker %d" % source)
            if source not in results:
                results[source] = []
            results[source].append(data)

        elif tag == tags.EXIT:

            print("Worker %d exited." % source)
            closed_workers += 1

    print("Master finishing")

    print(results)

else:
    # Worker processes execute code below
    name = MPI.Get_processor_name()

    print("I am a worker with rank %d on %s." % (rank, name))

    while True:

        comm.send(None, dest=0, tag=tags.READY)

        data = comm.recv(source=0, tag=MPI.ANY_SOURCE, status=status)
        #source = status.Get_source()
        tag = status.Get_tag()

        #print(source, tag)

        if tag == tags.START:

            # create some example array
            result = np.array([data])**2

            comm.send(result, dest=0, tag=tags.DONE)

        elif tag == tags.EXIT:

            comm.send(None, dest=0, tag=tags.EXIT)
            break
```